# Subject verb agreement has/have

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct?  You are one of the people who ***has*** or ***have*** helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct, depending on the subject. 
**Has** is used when the subject is singular, **have** is used when the subject is plural.

For example:

You are ***one of the people*** who has helped me.
(meaning: Out of a group of people, you are ***one*** who has helped me.)

You are one of ***the people who have helped me***.
(meaning: There is a group of people who have helped me, and you are one of them.)

Comment: That makes sense - I also like - You are ONE OF THE PEOPLE who has helped me.
(meaning: You are SOMEONE who has helped me.)

Comment: This is misleading. The subject of the sentence is *you*, which is singular because the complement *one* is singular. The subject of the relative clause is *who*, but its number is determined by its antecedent, which is (as you've pointed out) either *You* or *people*.

Comment: @deadrat: what? Isnt' the antecedent either "one" or "people"? I don't see how it can be "you".

Comment: @sumelic It doesn't matter since *You* = *one*.

Comment: @deadrat: The thing is that if "you" were the antecedent, I would expect subject-verb person agreement to be possible. "You" is not third-person. We can say things like "The one who helped me was you, who **have** my gratitude."

Comment: @sumelic That doesn't strike me as right, unless *you* is plural.

Comment: @deadrat: consider *[Is “It is you who are mistaken!” correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954)* and linked questions about similar sentences.

Comment: @deadrat: See for example "Yet inside the window is the person who is you, who **are** now looking out, shifted from the observer to the inside person and this shows in your work." ("Shifting Persona", Barbara Guest, in [*Poetics Journal Digital Archive](https://books.google.com/books?id=s57tBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA657&dq=%22is+you+who+are%22+-%22it+is+you+who+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI14KwpOjRAhUK6YMKHRlaC40Q6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22is%20you%20who%20are%22%20-%22it%20is%20you%20who%20are%22&f=false)* edited by Lyn Hejinian, and Barrett Watten)

Comment: @sumelic I'll defer to John Lawler, and I'll have to admit that *you who is* has started to sound a bit off to me. *You who are* is preferred by about 7:1 according to the Ngram viewer (Insert obligatory caution here). I had hoped that the first person would be dispositive, but I'll accept "I who is blameless" and "I who am blameless". YMMV

Answer (score -1):

Have is the correct form to use. People is plural hence have is the correct version. 
Your sentence requires the 'have' verb. Because it is a relative clause that modifies the noun 'people'. :)

Comment: It's ambiguous. The relative clause might modify the subject *you*, which is singular, or the complement *people*, which is plural.