# Should the pronoun "you" always take a plural verb?

Tags: verb-agreement, verb-forms

I'm writing a song, and I'd like to know if the pronoun "you" should always take a plural form.

I wrote these two lines:
It's You who never lies
It's You who purifies

I think it sounds wrong to say, "It's You who never lie."

The subject "it" is singular, and "You" refers to one person, so maybe the s-form is correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. "You" can be 1 person, 2 persons, 3 persons,,,
2. "You" always used like below.

You go there.(o)
You goes there.(x)
You tell a lie.(o)
You tells a lie.(x)

You can visit here for your grammar questions.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It’s funny that you would bring up ELL, because that’s where the question was [originally posted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271156/should-the-pronoun-you-always-take-a-plural-form). (It should have been closed as a duplicate on that site and not asked here.)

Answer (score 0):

In standard English, a clause with the second person pronoun "you" as the immediate subject always takes the same verb form used for a plural subject.

However, your examples have relative clauses, where "you" is not the immediate subject of the clause. The subject is instead the relative pronoun "who". "Who" in turn takes the personal pronoun "you" as its antecedent.

Clauses with the relative pronoun "who" as the subject have somewhat variable verb agreement. However, it would generally be considered correct to use the same agreement as "you" in your examples. A related question:
[Is "It is you who are mistaken!" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct) That would give "It's you who never lie" and "It's you who purify".

Comment: Are you saying it's correct either way? One answer for the question 'Is "It is you who are mistaken!" correct?' says '"It is you who is... " is out-and-out ungrammatical...' so I might just change the lines to "It's You. You never lie." & "It's You. You purify."