# You who think or thinks

Tags: relative-pronouns

Some days ago I heard a teacher saying the sentence:

I want to talk to you who thinks differently from the crowd.

It sounded unnatural, but if you consider that 'who' is the relative pronoun ruling the verb, he is right.
Can you clear that out to/ for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Was the teacher addressing one person, or several?

Comment: It's not incorrect and it's still confusing. Don't copy it.

Comment: Ok, thank you both! He was addressing one student only!

Comment: It's usually "you who think", "I who am", "those who are",  etc. You don't make verbs agree with "who".

Comment: Confusion may come from something like "You are he who thinks differently," where *thinks* goes with *he,* not *you,* as @PeterShor implies. This question must be a duplicate, but they can be difficult to find...

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Yes, in the example you quoted, it can be confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "It is you who are mistaken!" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct)

Answer (score 0):

Most speakers in most situations would make the verb agree with *you*. But there are attested examples where the agreement is instead with *who* treated as 3rd person singular. It is less common, for sure, but apparently acceptable for some native speakers.

> *And, believe me, woe to **you who insults** the intelligence community, if you're president.*  
> <sup>From *PBS NewsHour* for January 5, 2017, via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>
>
> *Everybody listening to **you who talks** about one of the great issues in American life today, which is the plight of the middle class…* 
> <sup>From *CBS 60 MINUTES* 2017/09/10, via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>
>
> *If you are doing your job right and attracting the best talent, then it is the entrepreneur who will be choosing you as opposed to **you who is** choosing the entrepreneur.* 
> <sup>From 'The Most Important Job Interview Question' - Anthony Tjan - Harvard 2012, via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>
>
> *We bow to **you who is** renowned as a Saint.*
>
> <sup>From a translation by Kurtis R. Schaeffer, in *Sources of Tibetan Tradition.* Kurtis R. Schaeffer, Matthew T. Kapstein, and Gray Tuttle, Eds. United States: Columbia University Press, 2013. [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sources_of_Tibetan_Tradition/VmkMBcsXxdkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+you+who+is%22&pg=PA296&printsec=frontcover)</sup>

Comment: Wow! Some many great examples! Thank you for your time!