# Is this sentence grammatically correct? If so, is it a good way to express it?

Tags: grammatical-number

Below is an excerpt from a book.

> I’m a man who loves traveling by myself. On every vacation in university, I spent about 7 to 10 days as a backpacker, traveling around China. **Since it was self-guiding tours**, no guide would come to help me arrange anything.

As I understand, **self-guiding tours** is a plural form so it should be **Since it were self-guiding tours**. Is my understanding correct? Or should it be changed to *Since they were self-guiding tours*? Which one is correct?

Comment: 'It' is a 'dummy subject' in your sentence. There's a nice explanation on dummy subjects  [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/can-it-be-used-with-plural-subject/205587#205587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" seems to refer to the collectively self-guiding nature of the holidays as a singular item, thus "it was" is appropriate, if a little awkward and clumsy. You could change it to "since these were self-guiding tours...". You cannot use a singular pronoun "it" with a plural verb "were".