# Does "it's ok to ..." count as a cleft construction?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clefts, it-its-itself

I am wondering if "it's ok to..." (e.g. as in "it's ok for us to leave now") would count as an it-cleft construction. When I consider Quirk et al.'s (1985) *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, it seems to me like all the components are given, the focus might be argued to lie on the "ok", and so forth - still, it seems a little odd to me and I am unsure about this. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: [Definition of "it-cleft" construction.](https://www.thoughtco.com/it-cleft-sentence-term-1691086)

Comment: No, it's not a cleft sentence; it's [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/279393/15299), with a dummy _it_ subject. The heavy infinitive subject _for us to leave now_ gets moved to the end and the dummy replaces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleft construction presupposes fronting of components that are usually placed elsewhere in syntactic terms: "My father lied" vs. "It's my father who lied". This case seems different since the it-clause is the canonical structure vs. less usual "for us to leave now is ok"

Comment: perfect, that makes sense, thanks!