# Is it correct to use the phrase 'It makes + sb + A + to ...'?

Tags: phrases

We've all known sentences like "It's kind of you to help me plant the flowers." are correct so I'm wondering if it can also apply to "*It makes...*". For example: "It makes me worried to see you watching TV all day."

Moreover, I've found this line somewhere and regarding this problem, I also want to ask if this is correct.

"It makes me unable to stop worrying about you to leave you on your own like this."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["It is having time to think that makes me depressed" — grammatical function of "that"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/it-is-having-time-to-think-that-makes-me-depressed-grammatical-function-of) 'It is having time to think that makes me depressed' is a cleft sentence, as explained in John Lawler's answer. 'It makes me sad to see you cry' is an it-clefted version of 'To see you cry makes me sad', which would usually be seen as 'Seeing you cry makes me sad'.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtlety here.

If the adjective can be easily changed into a verb, the best practice is to use the verb.

"It saddens me to see you glued to the TV all day."

"It worries me to see you glued to the TV all day."

However, if the adjective is *not* easily modified, then, yeah, "makes" is fine, as in:

"It makes me happy to see you glued to the TV all day."

Comment: Not just one subtlety. I'm not happy with "It makes me worried to see you glued to the TV all day" but find "It makes me worried, seeing you glued to the TV all day" quite idiomatic. / Well spotted.

Comment: I disagree that there is such a best practice as preferring a verb over an adjective. “It makes me sad to see you cry” is **far** more natural and idiomatic to me than “It saddens me to see you cry” – the latter is something I’d expect in poetry or Tolkien, but not in regular speech. “It makes me tired to see you working all the time” is a bit awkward, but “It tires me to see you working all the time” is far worse to me, in fact borderline ungrammatical.