# "It is ___ that/who + verb." pleonasm vs. "___ + verb."

Tags: word-usage, pleonasms

Is there a place for using these pleonasms:

- "It is John who runs." (instead of: "John runs.")
- "It was congress that legislated." (instead of: "Congress legislated.")

?

It would seem to have its use only when what comes after the "that" is a long clause: Example from the intro. of [Strunk & White](https://faculty.washington.edu/heagerty/Courses/b572/public/StrunkWhite.pdf):

> It is an old observation that the best writers sometimes disregard the rules of rhetoric.

could be rewritten as:

> That the best writers sometimes disregard the rules of rhetoric is an old observation.

But this isn't conciser.

Comment: Not passive, but an emphasis on the agent. **John** runs and **congress** legislated.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So it's just a matter of emphasizing the subject more than the verb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["It is having time to think that makes me depressed" — grammatical function of "that"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/it-is-having-time-to-think-that-makes-me-depressed-grammatical-function-of) (John Lawler's answer; it-clefts.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not exactly. I'm more interested in usage (in when such form should be used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more formal grammatical frameworks, the construction you're describing is called an "it-cleft." The standard view is that it-clefts are licensed when the clefted constituent ("John" in "It was John who...") is a FOCUS. A FOCUS is a discourse function that expresses new, exhaustive, or contrastive information. In contrast, the it-cleft is not licensed or sounds odd if the clefted element is a TOPIC. A TOPIC is old information. To illustrate, consider the example below:

> (1) a. **Which student** ate an apple?
> b. It was [FOCUS **John**] who ate an apple. 
> (= John has not been mentioned in the question, new information, FOCUS, so it's acceptable)

> (2) a. What did **John** do?
> b. ??It was [TOPIC **John**] who ate an apple. 
> (= John has been mentioned in the question, old information, TOPIC, so this sounds odd)

There is much, much more to say about this, but this would be a good starting point.

**Here is some literature on the topic.**

Gundel, Jeanette K. 1974. *The role of topic and comment in linguistic theory*. Ph.D.
dissertation, University of Texas at Austin. Re-issued 1988, in Jorge Hankamer,
ed. Outstanding Dissertations in Linguistics, Garland Publishing Co.

Prince, Ellen F. 1978. 'A comparison of wh-clefts and it-clefts in discourse.' *Language* 54, 883-906.

Reinhart, Tanya. 1981. 'Pragmatics and linguistics. An analysis of sentence
topics.' *Philosophica* 27, 53-94.

Rizzi, L. 1997. 'The Fine Structure of the Left Periphery. In L. Haegeman (ed.), *Elements of Grammar. Handbook in Generative Syntax*. Dordrecht: Kluwer, 281-337.

Rooth, Mats. 1985. *Association with Focus*. PhD thesis. Amherst: University of
Massachusetts.

Comment: Thank you! It- and wh-cleft is the terminology I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Emphasis is probably the usual driving force in such (and related) cleftings (as exemplified by your first two sentences):

From [ThoughtCo: Richard Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cleft-sentence-1689851) (bolding mine):

> In English grammar, a cleft is a construction in which some element in
> a sentence is moved from its normal position into a separate clause
> **to give it greater emphasis**. A cleft is also known as a cleft sentence, a cleft construction, and a cleft clause.
>
> "A cleft sentence is a sentence that is cleft (split) so as to put the
> focus on one part of it. The cleft sentence is introduced by it, which
> is followed by a verb phrase whose main verb is generally be. The
> focused part comes next, and then the rest of the sentence is
> introduced by a relative pronoun, relative determiner, or relative
> adverb. If we take the sentence *Tom felt a sharp pain after lunch*, two
> possible cleft sentences formed from it are *It was Tom who felt a
> sharp pain after lunch* and *It was after lunch that Tom felt a sharp
> pain.*"
>
> Take, for example, the simple declarative sentence, *Jerry went to the
> movie yesterday.* If you would want to emphasize one element or
> another, the sentence could be rewritten in several different ways:
>
> - *It was Jerry who went to the movie yesterday.*
> - *It was to the movie that Jerry went yesterday.*
> - *It was yesterday that Jerry went to the movie.*
>
> English has many different varieties of cleft constructions, but the
> two major types
> are it-clefts and wh-clefts. Wh- clefts use "wh" words, which is most
> often "what" in the construction. However, why, where, how, etc. are
> also possibilities.

That said, other perceived benefits are avoidance of awkward(-sounding) sentences:

- [Hmm] *That the best writers sometimes disregard the rules of rhetoric is an old observation.*
- *It is an old observation that the best writers sometimes disregard the rules of rhetoric.*

[Note that this similar-looking sentence is not a clefting; 'that' is the complementiser here, not a relativiser: Thanks to Richard Z for pointing this out.]
Also, when the first gap in your template is filled by an abstraction such as an idea, a more formal, solemn, dignified sentence can be generated:

> - *It is an indisputable truth that the Holocaust took place.*

[Again, complementiser 'that'.]

On the other hand,

- *John snores*

cannot be replaced by

- *It is John who snores*

in a simple statement of fact. The cleft sentence is marked for emphasis, identifying the guilty party.

Comment: Your example "It is an old observation that..." isn't an it-cleft. The "that" doesn't introduce a relative clause on "observation" but is a complement clause on "it" (expletive - associate structure). Contrast: "It is an observation that he made (not a guess)". vs. "It is an observation that the world is round."

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But it is OP who gives this example; you need to pick up on the two different structures in your own answer.