# What is the nature of That-complementizer here?

Tags: that, complements, predicative-complements

> It was in 1945 that World World 2 ended.

I think *that* is a **complementizer**, but I'm not sure of the nature of this complement. By nature I mean the part of speech of the complement clause and *to what* is it a complement.

It's neither the **subject** nor the **object** of this sentence. (compare *I think that World War 2 ended in 1945.*)

It not the **complement of a predicate adjective** either.
(compare *I am sure that World War 2 ended in 1945*.)

Maybe it's the complement to the prepositional/adverbial phrase *in 1945*? The reason I say this is because the that-clause couldn't just complement the *was* if the *in 1945* was removed.

Comment: Yes, _that_ is a complementizer here. It's part of this [_It_-Cleft transform](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57964/15299) of _World War II ended in 1945._

Comment: @JohnLawler But this sentence is quite different from **Having time to think makes me depressed.** or **You are mistaken.** where the NP is extracted and followed by a _that_ relative clause (adjectival in nature). If we were to do that with my sentence, we'd get **It was WW II that ended in 1945.** instead of **It was in 1945 that WW II ended.** The _in 1945_ is throwing me off because it's clearly abverbial in nature instead of adjectival. Anyways going back to my question: is the POS of the complement clause a noun clause? And to what is it a complement of?

Comment: As JL say, it's an _it_-cleft, but the expression _that World World 2 ended_ is a relative clause, not a complement, so "that" is analysed as a subordinating conjunction (aka subordinator) introducing the relative clause _that WW2 ended_. The basic non-cleft version is simply _WW2 ended in 1945_.

Comment: @BillJ If that is the indeed the case, what is antecedent of the relative clause _that World War 2 ended_? Because it should be modifying a noun no?

Comment: The foregrounded element (the antecedent) may be an NP, a PP, an AdvP or an AdjP. In your example, it's the PP "in 1945". Btw, in a cleft construction, the relative clause is not a modifier of the forgrounded element.

Comment: In other words, the relative clause does not form a constituent with its antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ The relative clause side of it does kind of show when you replace _that_ with _when_ as in **It was in 1945 when WW2 ended.** If it doesn't modify the antecedent, what is its purpose (and therefore what is its nature)? Is it just to introduce a subordinate clause and that's it?

Comment: The general idea is that _it_ -clefts have _it_ as the subject of the matrix clause, with the relative clause appearing in **extranuclear** position at the end. In _that_ relatives, _that_ introduces the relative clause. In _WH_ relatives, the relative clause is introduced by a relative pronoun like _which_ or _who_.

Comment: @BillJ So in most occurrences of _that_-relative clause, it references an antecedent and modifies it, but in a cleft-construction (or is it cleft-transformation?) the _that_ references an antecedent but doesn't modify it?

Comment: @Joe: Where did those sentences come from, and why are they relevant to what I said or what you asked? Those are completely different constructions. And, as for terminology, don't take BillJ too literally. He and I disagree on terminology. I often call things names he disapproves of; he'll be glad to tell you which.

Comment: @JohnLawler The two sentences are from the [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57954/is-it-is-you-who-are-mistaken-correct/57964#57964) you gave above and from a [hyperlink](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/it-is-having-time-to-think-that-makes-me-depressed-grammatical-function-of/53111#53111) within that link. They're relevant because in those links you explain "the Clefting process extracts the NP which becomes the predicate of a dummy _It_, and the rest becomes a relative clause modifying the NP", which are adjectival in nature. But not in my case above...?

Comment: There are several different types of clefts. _It_-Clefts are only one; there are also _Wh_-Clefts (_It was the green car that he took_ vs _What he took was the green car_, both from _He took the green car_). This is the wrong place to discuss clefting, anyway.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well going back to the original Q, does that mean _that_ is a complementizer of a noun clause _World World 2 ended in 1945_? And to what is it a complement of? You told me before that in _I am sure that World War 2 ended in 1945._ the that-clause is "a complement to the predicative adjective _sure_". Here I am asking the same question.

Comment: You're still missing the point: In _I am sure that World War 2 ended in 1945_ the _that_ clause is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of _sure_, with _that_ as subordinator (or 'complementizer' for some). But your original example is an _it_-cleft construction, where _that WW2 ended in 1945_ is a relative clause, again introduced by the subordinator (not complementizer) _that_. Is that clear now?

Comment: @BillJ It's clear, except for the part where you claim the relative clause in the original example (_that WW2 ended in 1945_) differs from the 'typical' relative clause in that it doesn't modify the antecedent. Original example: **It was in 1945 that WW2 ended.** Now compare it with a sentence like **1945 was the year that WW2 ended.** How does one argue that in the former sentence _that WW2 ended_ does NOT modify the antecedent, yet it does in the latter sentence?